# How to provide dynamic path to a file in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there any way to pass arguments in Spring Controller like we do in Standalone Java Application

```
    String filePath=args[0]
```

Here is the code below I want to provide file Path

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/someUrl/", method=RequestMethod.GET)

    String imageFilePath=? //Is there any way to pass the arguments here
```

Comment: you can send it in your request payload?

Comment: Well you can use @PathVariable. here's an example http://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-requestmapping-requestparam-pathvariable-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@PathVariable` annotation.

In your jsp send your request by sending some variable like

```
action=/${someurl}/
```

In your controller you can then use it ex:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{someurl}")
functionName (@PathVariable String yourUrl)
```